# Converting integers to bytes

Tags: python, string, binary, hex

The number should be DIRECTLY changed to a string where each byte represent each byte in the number, in that order.

For example, 303856920984473976136907479138614277609 should become '\xe4\x98\xb6\xdb\xed~\x1c\xd2X\xa5\xd1\xa9\xdaNu\xe9'

```
>>>hex(303856920984473976136907479138614277609)
'0xe498b6dbed7e1cd258a5d1a9da4e75e9L'
>>>>>> 'e498b6dbed7e1cd258a5d1a9da4e75e9'.decode('hex')
'\xe4\x98\xb6\xdb\xed~\x1c\xd2X\xa5\xd1\xa9\xdaNu\xe9'
```

Is there a python function to do this directly?

Comment: 'Hex' isn't an encoding.

Comment: @F3AR3DLEGEND: In 3.x, no. But it exists in 2.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "decoding" you do is very brittle, so here's something a bit more rigorous:

```
import struct
from functools import partial
from itertools import imap

def to_bytes(number):
    # This can only pack an unsigned long long
    # so we need to split the number into those
    packer = partial(struct.pack, ">Q")

    # How many unsigned long longs needed to hold the number
    iterations = (number.bit_length() // 64) + 1

    # Get the parts
    sections = ((number >> i*64) & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF for i in reversed(xrange(iterations)))

    # And map "packer" over them
    return b"".join(imap(packer, sections)).lstrip("\x00")
```

It's not really "built-in" but it doesn't break for lots of numbers:

```
>>> to_bytes(0x12300FFABACAADABAF0)
'\x01#\x00\xff\xab\xac\xaa\xda\xba\xf0'

>>> hex(0x12300FFABACAADABAF0)[2:].decode('hex')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/hex_codec.py", line 42, in hex_decode
    output = binascii.a2b_hex(input)
TypeError: Non-hexadecimal digit found
```

and it's arguably cleaner than going through `hex`, striping trailing and preceeding non-numeral characters, padding with zero if need be and then transcoding.

In Python 3 it's a lot easier:

```
>>> number.to_bytes(number.bit_length()//8+1, "big")
b'\x01#\x00\xff\xab\xac\xaa\xda\xba\xf0'
```

---

```
%~> python2
Python 2.7.5 (default, May 12 2013, 12:00:47) 
[GCC 4.8.0 20130502 (prerelease)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> (324).bit_length()
9
```

Comment: number.bit_length()
integers have no such attribute

Comment: What version of Python are you on? "Evidence" is added in my post. You can simulate it with `int(math.ceil(math.log2(number)))` if you're sure you don't have it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a standard function to do it, you can define one easily:

```
def to_bytes(number):
    return ("%x" % number).decode('hex')
```